# ajax write event in weekcalendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, date, calendar

I am using this calendar in one of my applications : https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

I have set it up so that i can pull my events into the calendar with an ajax call. However writing new events is not working somehow. I think the problem is withing the json object more specific the 2 dates.

currently i haeve following code:

calendar.js:

```
'Bewaren' : function() {
              calEvent.id = id;
              id++;
              calEvent.start = (startField.val());
              calEvent.end = (endField.val());
              calEvent.title = titleField.val();
              calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

              var cct = $.cookie('csrfeval');
              console.log(cct);
              $calendar.weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
              $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
              $dialogContent.dialog("close");
              var data_item = {
                    "start": calEvent.start,
                    "end" :   calEvent.end,
                    "title" : calEvent.title,
                    "body" :  calEvent.body,   
                    "csrfeval": cct
                };
                var target="/evaluatie/ajax/bewaaragendaitem";


                $.ajax({
                    url: target,
                    data: data_item,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        notify("Ajax error");
                        if (errorThrown != 'abort' && XMLHttpRequest.status != 0) {
                        notify('unable to get data, error:' + textStatus);
                      }
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                      //self._renderEvents(data, $weekDayColumns);

                        notify('Ok');
                    }
                  });
           }
```

ajax.php:

```
         function bewaaragendaitem(){

    print_r($_POST);

}
```

the error i get

[image: error]

This is the object being sent (wich i think the date is causing errors...)

[image]

Anyone that can help me to build the json object to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are feeding a text string into a function that wants a date object. The object you have shown does have date objects in it, but clearly they are not getting where they need to go.

This is hard to debug because your code is a little unclear - you have commented the line that seems to trigger the display of data:

```
self._renderEvents(data, $weekDayColumns);
```

It would also help to be able to know what self is referring to. Is __renderEvents() your own function or part of the library?

Use the 'break on error' feature of firebug (click the red circle to the lower left of the error box) and run it again. You should find that the code stops before the error causes it to terminate and you can then use the stack pane to see what object has been passed in the where. It looks like you have minified/compressed JavaSCript in your error message, so you would find it easier if you switch to the debug version of whatever library that file is from (jQuery, presumably) so that you can see each command on a separate line.